# Trilogy of books featuring featuring ice age spacefaring civilization

Tags: story-identification

I don't remember the latter two books, but I remember the first. In the first book we are in another dark age, and receive an extraterrestrial signal. This forces a group of scientists to help uplift human civilization, and travel to the extraterrestrial signal's planet of origin. There it is discovered they are a lost human colony from a previous advanced ice age human civilization.

Does anyone remember the titles of the books or the series name?

Comment: This is actually a relatively common [trope](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/LostColony); http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Literature/TerreEnFuite  for example...

Answer (score 4):

I'd guess you're remembering the [Trigon Disunity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Trigon_Disunity) series by [Michael P. Kube-Mcdowell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_P._Kube-McDowell).

[image]

> Synopsis
>
> The devastating Food and Fuel Wars have turned once-powerful nations
>   into isolated farming communities. Barter has replaced currency , and
>   scientist - considered responsible for the world's misery, are burned
>   at the stake. Hidden in the Idaho hills, astronomer Allen Chandliss
>   secretly monitors his radio telescope, listening for signs of
>   intelligent life, hoping that aliens will come and improve things on
>   Earth. For seventeen years he has waited patiently. His patience is
>   about to pay off...

Comment: Trigon Disunity is the series I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: To help build your reputation as well as the answerer's, be sure to click on the check mark to mark the answer as correct.

Comment: It's been a while since I read this trilogy, but iirc the ice age space faring civilisation was named after the [Weichselian glaciation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weichselian_glaciation)